# Automatically redraw MainPage

Tags: .net, windows-runtime

In the application for winrt first start the update of status on the TextBlock, and then start the long process of calculation. The main form does not have time to be redrawn and no change in display of the status. How can i redraw it automatically?

Comment: The calculation should take place in a `BackgroundWorker` (or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are probably blocking the UI thread (because you are performing the long running opperation on the UI thread), so it prevent you UI to be refreshed. 
To do that you can do something like that:

```
    public async Task<Result> ExecuteLongOperationAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => ExecuteLongOperation());
    }
```